Customize exercise and solution environment using xsim
I am trying to typeset a document with a section on exercises and solutions. Here is my MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{item}
  {\item[\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}]}
  {}
\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template=item,
  solution/template=item,
  solution/print = true,
}

\newenvironment{exercises}
  {\section{Exercises}\description}
  {\enddescription}


  
\begin{document}

\begin{exercises}
  \begin{exercise}
    My exercise.
  \end{exercise}
  \begin{solution}
    My answer.
  \end{solution}
  \begin{exercise}
    My second exercise.
  \end{exercise}
  \begin{solution}
    Answer to my second exercise.
  \end{solution}
\end{exercises}

\end{document}



This is my output:

How can I make the term "Solution" (as in "Solution" 1, "Solution" 2 etc) italic and bold?
Thank you!

The formatting is made by the description environment.
As you want to keep bold the word "Solution", you can just add the italic shape in the template:
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{itemitalized}
  {\item[\textit{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}]}
  {}

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{item}
  {\item[\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}]}
  {}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{itemitalized}
  {\item[\textit{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}]}
  {}


\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template=item,
  solution/template=itemitalized,
  solution/print = true,
}

\newenvironment{exercises}
  {\section{Exercises}\description}
  {\enddescription}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercises}
  \begin{exercise}
    My exercise.
  \end{exercise}
  \begin{solution}
    My answer.
  \end{solution}
  \begin{exercise}
    My second exercise.
  \end{exercise}
  \begin{solution}
    Answer to my second exercise.
  \end{solution}
\end{exercises}

\end{document}



Thank you so much!
